# TextField in SwiftUI resets after every keystroke

Tags: swift, swiftui

in this script the TextField is shown, but it resets to "player 1" after every keystroke. Can anyone help me?

```
import SwiftUI

class Player: ObservableObject {
    @Published var playerData = "player 1"
}

let player = Player()

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var player: Player
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("player", text: $player.playerData)
    }  
}
```

Tried with other code, but without success.

Comment: How do you initialize `player`?

Comment: Do I need to initialize "player"? Class Player has only one variable with a value.

Comment: Yes you do need to initialise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Player: ObservableObject {
    @Published var playerData = "player 1"
    
    static let shared = Player()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var player = Player.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("player", text: $player.playerData)
    }
}
```

However, usually the model store would be an `environmentObject` `PlayerStore` and would contain an array of `Player` model structs.

Comment: So the solution is to turn your View Model into a singleton? this doesn't seem like a good solution